# Maven with Cygwin - Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly

Tags: java, maven, cygwin

I'm trying to run Maven on cygwin. I've added maven to the path and my Java home looks like this:

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME 
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0
```

Yet when I try to run `mvn --version`, I get this:

```
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_01/bin/java
```

Any idea why it's not working? Java -version works fine, so it's not a problem with java. I've also tried jdk1.6.0 instead.

Running `which java` gives,

```
$ which java
/cygdrive/c/windows/system32/java
```

and `java -version` gives,

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_01"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_01-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 21.1-b02, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: do you need to escape the space in Program Files with a \? I never install anything dev related into Program Files just because of that stupid space.

Comment: I escaped it but it gives the same error. I also don't like the space in Program Files, but I'd prefer not to change the way I use windows just because of cygwin.

Comment: what does `which java` print out?  and `java -version`?

Comment: @jtahlborn I added the outputs to the question.

Comment: @gsingh2011 Have you added JAVA_HOME to your Windows environment variables? You may need that.

Comment: You can try this in Cygwin environment: `export JAVA_HOME='/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0'` or `set JAVA_HOME='/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0'` The quotes are needed since there are spaces in the path.

Comment: If the problem still persists, can you add the output of `echo $PATH` to your question? Even if `$JAVA_HOME` points to where you want it to, it's useless if it's not in your path. I use Maven with Cygwin daily with JDK 7 and I have no problem. See my [`.bashrc`](https://github.com/kohanyirobert/cygwin/blob/master/.bashrc) and the variables defined in it, maybe it'll help to solve your problem. Although it's strange that Maven won't run with JDK 7 (which is obviously in your path). Your `$PATH` holds the truth I guess.

Comment: Which Maven version are you trying to run?

Comment: Did you try Stefan's solution? Run `mvn.bat` instead of `mvn`. It worked for me, though I was trying to run `ant`, not `mvn`

Answer (score 17):

If I run `mvn.bat` instead of `mvn`, I didn't have this problem.

So, since Cygwin will run the mvn file, I replaced this mvn file with a softlink (`ln -s mvn.bat mvn`) to the batch file. This way, running `mvn` will silently run the `mvn.bat` which handles these problems gracefully.

Comment: I had the same problem, I was trying to run ant from cygwin. The JAVA_HOME path was definitely correct, running ant.bat instead of ant did fix my problem

Comment: I have the same problem with Gradle: I wanted to start a maven build from within Gradle, but when 'mvn' is executed from within the gradle script, JAVA_HOME is suddenly "corrected" to the /cygdrive/-path (instead of the C:\..-path it is upon invocation of gradle), and thus the maven invoker which evidently operates in dos-space can't find java. Anyone knows who changes the JAVA_HOME?! It seems like this is the only env-var which gets this treatment. (It might seem like it has something to do with the 'cmd /c' style invocation of the subprocess).

Answer (score 11):

Anyone Using Cygwin and Maven, here's exactly what you need:

In your Cygwin bash prompt:

```
$ vim ~/.bashrc
```

or:

```
$ nano ~/.bashrc
```

(Which ever you fancy...)

Append the following:

```
alias mvn=mvn.bat
```

Save and Exit. Then run:

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

Now you should be able to use the `mvn` command as you do in cmd prompt.

Comment: This works great just use `alias mvn=mvn.cmd`

Answer (score 4):

Cygwin uses a dos console to execute Maven builds (`mvn.bat`).

Set your Java home to the `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_01` location.

Comment: actually this is the most correct way to solve that. All cygwin tools undestand windows-style `JAVA_HOME`, but not vice versa.

Comment: It worked for my hard drive but not for flash drive. using mvn.bat worked for both cases, I'm clueless why this should be so!

Answer (score 0):

Setting `JAVA_HOME` to `/cygdrive/c/Progra~1/Java/jdk1.6.0` might help.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem while running gradle from cygwin tool.

I used to set the Java home including the `bin` folder:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin
```

But later I realized that some application do not recognize if you include bin folder, so I changed the class path to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67` and it started working.