# maven error when running in cygwin?

Tags: maven, cygwin, maven-3

I have cygwin in Windows 7 and downloaded and installed maven "binaries" and have the following set

```
export JAVA_HOME=/cygdrive/c/java/jdk1.7.0_11
export MAVEN_HOME=/usr/apache-maven-3.0.5
export M2_HOME=/home/MyUser/.m2
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$MAVEN_HOME/bin:$PATH

$ which java
/cygdrive/c/java/jdk1.7.0_11/bin/java

$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_11"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_11-b21)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.6-b04, mixed mode)

$ which mvn
/usr/apache-maven-3.0.5/bin/mvn

$ mvn -version
Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher
```

I've looked at [Maven error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118237/maven-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-codehaus-plexus-classworlds-l) but it did not address my issue.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Maven with Cygwin - Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524367/maven-with-cygwin-error-java-home-is-not-defined-correctly)

The "alias mvn=mvn.bat" answer toward the bottom of above post worked for me. However, is this THE solution?

Answer (score 1):

I spent a couple of hours fruitlessly fiddling with different combinations of JAVA_HOME, M2_HOME and M2 after this same problem.  Finally I set down to debugging the mvn script (by changing line 1 to read "`#!/bin/sh -x`").  It occurs because the script is relying on shell globbing to get the correct version of the .jar file (at approx. line 157):

```
CLASSPATH="${M2_HOME}/boot/plexus-classworlds-*.jar"
```

the ***** is not being expanded, for some reason globbing is disabled;
Hence the command the script attempts to execute is:

```
'/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_40/bin/java' -classpath 'D:\apps\apache-maven-3.0.4\boot\plexus-classworlds-*.jar' '-Dclassworlds.conf=D:\apps\apache-maven-3.0.4\bin\m2.conf' '-Dmaven.home=D:\apps\apache-maven-3.0.4' org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher -version
```

when it should be:

```
'/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_40/bin/java' -classpath 'D:\apps\apache-maven-3.0.4\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar' '-Dclassworlds.conf=D:\apps\apache-maven-3.0.4\bin\m2.conf' '-Dmaven.home=D:\apps\apache-maven-3.0.4' org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher -version
```

Solution: Edit the "mvn" script and change line 157 to read:

```
CLASSPATH="$(echo ${M2_HOME}/boot/plexus-classworlds-*.jar)"
```

Answer (score -2):

change the JAVA_HOME path in .bashrc_profile file